# How to get a certain value from enum?

Tags: python, enums

I have the following class:

```
class YesOrNn(enum.Enum):
  YES = "Y"
  NO = "N"
```

I am getting my inputs such as `YesOrNo("true")` or `YesOrNo("false")`,

To make this work, I think I need to change the class to:

```
class YesOrNn(enum.Enum):
  YES = "true"
  NO = "false"
```

But, I also have a case where whenever a variable's value is saved as `YesOrNo.YES.value`, it should answer `"Y"`.

I can't seem to figure out how to pull that off

Comment: You write a function to handle the parsing / display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [`_missing_` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Enum._missing_):

```
import enum

class YesOrNo(enum.Enum):

    YES = "Y"
    NO = "N"

    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        if value.lower() in ('y', 'yes', 'true', 't'):
            return cls.YES
        elif value.lower() in ('n', 'no', 'false', 'f'):
            return cls.NO
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.